# can split string method of java return the array with the delimiters as well

Tags: java, string, split

When we use `String.Split()` method on a string to split in java, it works as following:

```
String s = "hello my dear";
String[] ss = s.split("[ ]");
```

The array `ss` contains `[Hello, my, dear]` but the spaces (which are the delimiters) in this case are not the part of array.

is there some way that the delimiters may be the part of the array generated using the split method of string class in Java.

Comment: I don't think so, but I imagine it wouldn't be that hard to just manually add the delimiter.

Comment: You can't do that using the `String#split` method. Instead, I guess it could be done using a RegularExpression that searches through the String data and add every result and the delimiter in an `String[]` or a `List<String>`.

Comment: @JesseJ, bad methodology!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this: -

```
"hello my dear".split("(?<=[ ])");
```

It splits on a empty string just after a whitespace. This will give you array with elements like this: -

```
hello_
my_
dear
```

`_` means space.

---

If you want your delimiter to be separate array element, you can do it like this: -

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("a+b=c".split("(?<=[+=])|(?=[+=])")));
```

This now splits on empty string, which is either followed by either `+ or =`, or preceded by either `+ or =`. So, the all the locations where the split is performed for the above case is like this: -

```
a + b = c
 ^ ^ ^ ^    <-- Empty strings before and after your pattern - `[+=]`
```

So, you have 5 elements in your array.

**Output: -**

```
[a, +, b, =, c]
```

But you are using the wrong tool for parsing mathematical expression. You should not use Regex for this.

Comment: I guess OP wants/needs a result array like [hello, _, my, _, dead] (based on your sample).

Comment: assume my string is a+b=c, and i need [a,+,b,=,c] as a result of split. what should i do ?

Comment: @adeeliqbal if that's the String you should parse, you should not use a RegEx in the first place. Write a real example of your needs and your problem in order that community could help you.

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. What are you trying to achieve by parsing your mathematical expression with regex?

Comment: @RohitJain i don't have to parse only mathematical expression. it is just an example. string tokenizer worked well to solve my problem. but my supervisor saying that it can be done using split method of string.

Comment: @adeeliqbal. Yeah it can sure be done, and I've added the example for that, and you should almost always use `String#split` whereever you are using `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: @RohitJain thanks , your last example works. but i need a bit more support. in case i have a long list of delimiters, what would be the best way. suppose i have to parse a java file using split method of string class.

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. You should in no way parse a Java file or any file with a `split` method. You should use `Scanner` class instead. Take a look at the documentation of `Scanner`. Whenever you want to read a file for parsing, go for `Scanner`.

Comment: @RohitJain thanks. i think i may first study it and then proceed further. thanks again SIR!

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. Sure. First get your hands dirty with basic stuffs you can do with Scanner. Then you can dig further step by step. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

use [StringTokenizer's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) overloaded constructor:

```
String s = "hello my dear";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " ", true);
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Output:

```
hello

my

dear
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on  word boundaries.

```
    String[] ts = "hello my dear".split("\\b");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ts));

[, hello,  , my,  , dear]
```

---

***Alternatively***

```
public String[] getParts(String s) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        parts.add(m.group());
    }
    return parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
}
```

This matches with every find either a word `\\w+` (small w) or a non-word character `\\W` (capital W).

Comment: if my string is s="hello my dear; a=b+c";    and i need result as [hello, ,my, ,dear,;, ,a,=,b,+,c] .....

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. Are you actually trying to get all the words from your string? Your examples tends me to think like that.

Comment: For "abc = (def+ -7)" one would get: "", "abc", " = (", "def", "+ -", "7", ")". So `split` half ways solves the splitting.

Comment: @RohitJain yes, i need all the words from the string.

Comment: @adeeliqbal. o.O wait. `+` and `=` are not words. To get just words would be simple task.

Comment: @JoopEggen yes you are right. but i need "=","(" separate rather than "=(" together. is is possible ?

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. Can't you just modify the example that I posted to work for your example. I think, that would be fairly an easy task. Try something on your own now. That is the way you learn.

Comment: Okay, added a full solution.