# Splitting string into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am attempting to split the components of a string into an array, so that they can be accessed more easily.

For example: `4+5=` should become `['4','+','5','=']`.

**Edit: -**
I would need consecutive numbers to be joined together, and whitespaces can be ignored. Thanks again!

Comment: [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), dude :)

Comment: are your strings always number-operator-number-equals or are there other possible strings?

Comment: I just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032850/can-split-string-method-of-java-return-the-array-with-the-delimiters-as-well/14032866#14032866)

Comment: I guess, you need to edit your question, as you need a parsed result and not just array of single characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it with regex [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism.

```
String str = "10 * 10 - 40 + 100/2 = 110";

//but first lets remove white spaces (it will makes regex easier)
String strWithoutSpaces=str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

String[] tokens = strWithoutSpaces.split("(?<=[-+*/=])|(?=[-+*/=])");

for (String t:tokens)
    System.out.print(t+",");
```

Output:

```
10,*,10,-,40,+,100,/,2,=,110,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String str = "4+5=";
String[] tokens = str.split("(?!^)");
for (String s : tokens) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This will output

```
4  
+  
5  
=
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use toCharArray() method

```
    String s ="4+5=";
    char [] stArr = s.toCharArray();
    for(char ss: stArr){
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
```

Out put

```
4
+
5
=
```

Comment: This will break for `45+45=90`

Comment: Will again break. It now splits on empty string.

Comment: @Rohit I tested. Neither `toCharArray` broke nor empty `split` one. Please can you explain, why you envisage it would be wrong?

Comment: @mtk.. toCharArray will treat `4` and `5` as different characters in case of `45+45=90`. OP want them to be together. It returns this array: - `['4', '5', '+', '4', '5'...]`

Comment: @Rohit Thanks for that. I misinterpreted the question. My bad... Great answer to the other similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "45+5-26";
    String strArr[] = new String[str.length()];
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if (ch != '\0') {
            if (ch == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            if (ch >= 48 && ch <= 57) {
                sb.append(ch);
                continue;
            } else {
                strArr[cnt++] = sb.toString();
                sb = new StringBuffer();
                // sb.append(ch);
            }
            strArr[cnt++] = ch + "";
            sb = new StringBuffer();
        }
    }
    strArr[cnt++] = sb.toString();
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.println("strArray: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        if (strArr[i] == null)
            break;
        System.out.println(strArr[i]);
    }
}
```

If you have only operators as the separator between the numbers this would be more easy to get the string tokens.
You can modify as below if you want the tokens separated by a comma:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        if (strArr[i] == null)
            break;
          //    System.out.println(strArr[i]);
        if(i!=0)
            sbResult.append(",");
        sbResult.append(strArr[i]);

    }
    System.out.println("sbResult: "+sbResult.toString());
```