# split string method

Tags: java, regex, string, split

i have written a code in java as given under

```
public class sstring  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
    String s="a=(b+c); string st='hello adeel';";  
    String[] ss=s.split("\\b");  
    for(int i=0;i<ss.length;i++)  
        System.out.println(ss[i]);  
    }  
}
```

and the output of this code is

```
a
=(
b
+
c
);
string

st
='
hello

adeel
';
```

what should i do in order to split =(  or  ); etc  in two separate elements rather than single elements. in this array. i.e. my output may look as

```
a
=
(
b
+
c
)
;
string

st
=
'
hello

adeel
'
;
```

is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. See this answer: - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14032866/1679863

Comment: Just noticed that the question was asked by you only. Now what didn't you understand in that solution?

Comment: actually consecutive special characters are not separated. that's why

Comment: @RohitJain thanks for your support. i think that string tokenizer class would best suit my problem. isn't it ?

Comment: @adeeliqbal.. Have you tried to modify the `split` method I gave to suit your situation. Just include all the delimiters you have in that character class. In this case, you have `\\W`. So, you can use it. StringTokenizer may work, but it is not suggested to use it.

Comment: So, you need to use this: - `s.split("(?<=\\W)|(?=\\W)");`. I have just replaced `[+=]` with `\\W`. It will not split on empty string followed or preceded by `non-word` character. And that is what you want here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code there..

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("a=(b+c); string st='hello adeel';");
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This matches with every find either a word `\\w+` (small w) or a non-word character `\\W` (capital W).

It is an unaccepted answer of [can split string method of java return the array with the delimiters as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032850/can-split-string-method-of-java-return-the-array-with-the-delimiters-as-well/14032866#14032866) of the above comment of @RohitJain.

```
public String[] getParts(String s) {
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+|\\W)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        parts.add(m.group());
    }
    return parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Just to my surprise, even the asker is same. ;)

Comment: @RohitJain okay, today enough with SO ;S

Comment: @JoopEggen.. Lol ;) Good night :)